# How to get correct values from Arduino sensors

Tags: arduino, hardware

I am using 6 different sensors which are working simultaneously, but I got a problem in the readings from **LM35 temperature sensor** and **MQ-7 Carbon Monoxide sensor**. The values are changing depending on the power source.

How can I fix this problem? I'm planning to use a Sony power bank to feed my system but I am getting the wrong values especially from the temperature sensor.

Comment: circuit schema, codes or any thing else can help to solve your problem

Comment: Try electronics stack exchange. This is NOT a code problem

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is not a hardware problem.

Answer (score 0):

Although, it's not a coding problem my suggestion is you can use signal conditioning to solved this. Search about low pass filter and high pass filter to filtering frequency in output sensor.

The simple method is using voltage divider, like this:

Vout = (R1/R1+R2) * Vin

R1 is your sensor, and R2 is resistor.